# Android - ImageView On Click

Tags: android, touch

Im trying to trace a click when my image view is clicked, but I cannot seem to pick up the touch, any ideas?

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, " click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Images normally aren't clickable, therefore I would suggest that you put the definition

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

in your layout.xml to the imageView.

If this is not helping, please edit+update your question and show us the part of your layout, where you define the image to have a look at it.

EDIT:
Tried it, and your code worked with me too - even with the upper case id name.
Can you please have a close look at your LogCat? 
Mine sometimes doesn't really update, as long as I don't choose the device again.

To do so in Eclipse, go to the View "Devices" (or show it first via "Window") and click once on your device / virtual device.

If you still don't find your log entry in the LogCat-View, try to create a filter (via the green plus and giving it the String you defined with `TAG` as "by Log Tag").

Have a look at [android developers > Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html#using-ddms) at the section "Using LogCat"

Comment: I'm perfectly able to use the suggested code without setting `android:clickable`.

Comment: setonclicklistener makes a view clickable if it doesn't have that as a default.

Comment: ok good to know. guess I got confused - you would need that if you want to use the android:onClick and have a link to a method there. well then I hope we get an update on the second part of my answer.

Comment: @Machado good point. This attribute didn't exist when I first gave this answer. Added it now in case others come across this post

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to override the onClick method. This works for me and should do for you as well :-)

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   //@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.v(TAG, " click");         
   }        
});
```

Here's to get the X and Y coordinates:

```
imgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      // X = event.getX()
      // Y = event.getY()
      return false;
   }            
});
```

Comment: "Annotation type used to mark methods that override a method declaration in a superclass. Compilers produce an error if a method annotated with @Override does not actually override a method in a superclass."

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Override.html

Comment: I get the error:
The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: Could you please post your entire code, or at least everything that's relevant to the ImageView?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
   // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refresh);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.v(TAG, " click");         
        }        
     });

Comment: Isn't the @Override annotation just a marker that can but doesn't need to be used? The overriding takes place anyway - no matter if its there or not.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This seems to be a common issue if you're using a JRE below 1.6.0. It seems that all you need to do is comment out the @Override annotation.

Comment: Got this working now, thanks. How can I get the x and y pos of the click?

Comment: For that, you'll need an OnTouchListener. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

1) First make your image view clickable by adding-> android:clickable="true" .
2) Then go to your java file and add declare a variable 
for example->  private static ImageView imgview;
3) Then add this functionality:

```
public void OnclickButtonListener() {

    imgview =  findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          Intent intent=new Intent(timetable.this,MapsActivity.class);
                                          startActivity(intent);
                                      }
    });
}
```

and call this function in the constructor.
Hopefully this would work.