# android - How to play video in the image view

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-video-player

I want to play video in the image view. I mean, if user taps on the some portion of the image then the video will play. is it possible? please can anyone help me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add `ImageView` and `VideoView` in `RelativeLayout` and set `ImageView` to invisible and `VideoView` to visible and vice-versa and you can play video on onClick.

Comment: But How do we know this image having the video and How do we perform click operation? I mean, I want to play the video if we click on the some portion of the text.

Comment: check this link hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892270/how-to-play-video-in-android-on-click

Answer (score 0):

You can use framelayout having imageview on above and videoview at back. and when ever the user clicks on the imageview then you can hide the imageview and start the video using video view.