# ImageView Click not working in android service Custom layout

Tags: android, layout, service, click

ImageView click is not working on custom layout creatd in android service.

```
public class CallService extends Service {
String incomingnumber;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    incomingnumber = intent.getExtras().getString("incomingnumber");
    System.out.println("=== onStartCommand incomingnumber : " + incomingnumber);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup mView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.testactivity, null);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);


    ImageView imgCallPick = mView.findViewById(R.id.imgCallPick);
    ImageView imgCaller = mView.findViewById(R.id.imgCaller);

    imgCaller.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("===== imgCaller");
            return false;
        }
    });

    wm.addView(mView, params);
} }
```

i just create custom layout in service, the layout contain a diff view but the Imageview click not working. is there any solution for that, then help me.

Thanks

Comment: can u try to print a `toast` or `Log` in `onTouch`

Comment: yes i try both print and Toast

Comment: i try also add OnClickListener but not working

Comment: no no u print the `LOG` if u touch on Image then in Logcat show the msg or not

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207067/how-to-implement-touch-listener-on-image

Comment: yes i understant what u say

Comment: i try both but not toast is show and nither log is printing in my logcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166759/discussion-between-gaurav-mandlik-and-mohammad-ali).

Answer (score 1):

From this answer: [Android - ImageView On Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326601/android-imageview-on-click)

Add in your xml layout:

> android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to use of deprecated param

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
```

For getting touch events

Use this if you want a colored background

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.RGB_565);
```

Use this if you want a transparent background

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Everything else remains same :)

Comment: Have you given all the permission correctly. I am using the same code. Which SDK version are you using?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26,buildToolsVersion "26.0.3",minSdkVersion 15,targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'